# xlsxwriter: how to load a BytesIO png files created with matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: matplotlib, python-3.5, xlsxwriter

python==3.5.2,  matplotlit==3.0.0, pandas 0.24.0. numpy==1.15.4 on windows 10.

When saving a matplotlib figure using matplotlib's savefig and exporting it to an excel file using xlsxwriter, sometimes the saving to a png file is a little behind the export to excel causing the png file to "not be seen", hence not to be exported to the excel. 
I thought of saving the figure into a buffer:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from io import BytesIO

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(10, 3)),
                                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
# make plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(ax =ax)

# save plot
buffy = BytesIO()
fig.savefig(buffy, format='png')
buffy.seek(0)
img_data = buffy.read()

# export plot to an xlsx file
wb  = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test_BytesIO.xlsx')
ws = wb.add_worksheet('the_pic')
ws.insert_image('A1', 'image.png', {'image_data': img_data})

wb.close()
```

But, I am struggling for exporting the file to the excel sheet using xlsxwriter. 
Any lead will be appreciated.

Edit

@jmcnamara: Adding any file name such as 'image.png', does not help either:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:...\binary_save_plt.py",
>   line 24, in 
>       wb.close()   File "C:\Users...\Python35\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line
>   306, in close
>       self._store_workbook()   File "C:\Users...\Python35\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line
>   637, in _store_workbook
>       self._prepare_drawings()   File "C:\Users...\Python35\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line
>   1073, in _prepare_drawings
>       self._get_image_properties(filename, image_data)   File "C:\Users...\Python35\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line
>   1143, in _get_image_properties
>       data = image_data.getvalue() AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'getvalue'

Comment: When you use insert_image() with image_data like in your example then you can give any name as the filename such as ‘image.png’.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the above to reflect the results of the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `image_data` parameter needs to be a BytesIO object (not the data from it). And you can give any suitable name for the image as the filename. See the docs on [insert_image()](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-insert-image).

The following should work:

```
buffy = BytesIO()
fig.savefig(buffy, format='png')

wb  = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test_BytesIO.xlsx')
ws = wb.add_worksheet('the_pic')
ws.insert_image('A1', 'image.png', {'image_data': buffy})
```